# Is IBM a supported provider for Terraform?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-tools

Can anyone tell me what if there are any plans to add IBM Object storage to the list of providers for Terraform? 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/
Per these posts, people are using it on IBM.

IBM does have a couple of docs referring to Terraform, but it does not appear to have gone through IBM's AIT certification process. 
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-getting-started#install
https://ibm-cloud.github.io/tf-ibm-docs/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: This IBM Cloud tutorial (and some others) has Terraform: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-plan-create-update-deployments In the related GH repo is code that deploy COS https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/multiple-environments-as-code/blob/master/terraform/per-environment/main.tf